# Open prettyPhoto Gallery with FontAwesome Icon

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, prettyphoto

I have been searching around and I couldn't find any post related to my Issue, so I decided to ask on Stackoverflow. I have this simple prettyPhoto gallery which I need to open via a FontAwesome Icon in a lightbox. Can someone please help me out?

***CODE:***

**Photos:**

I have a `foreach` loop in PHP which renders images for each gallery in their respective gallery which in this case is `pp_gal`

```
foreach ($talent_photos as $image) {
    echo "<a href='{$image['url']}' rel='prettyPhoto[pp_gal]'><img src='{$image['url']}' width='{$image['width']}' height='{$image['height']}' alt='{$image['alt']}' /><br></a><br>";
}
```

**Icon:**

This is the Markup for the Icon by which they gallery should be opened in a lightbox.

```
<a class="icon-btn lens-icon"><br>
    <img src="http://192.55a.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/lens.png" alt=""><br>
</a>
```

I hope I explained this correctly, if I didn't please let me know ..

Thanks ..

Comment: Why are you using  lens.png if you want a font-awesome icon to open the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

On prettyPhoto plugin page, there is no documentation for the plugin methods, so the best way is to trigger a click event on the first element of your gallery.

So on the fontAwesome button add the prettyPhoto gallery id eg:

```
<a class="icon-btn lens-icon" data-gallery="prettyPhotto[pp_gal]"><br>
    <img src="http://192.55a.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/lens.png" alt=""><br>
</a>
```

Than you can trigger this from your JavaScript :

```
$("[data-gallery]").click(function(){
    var galleryID = $(this).data("gallery");
    $("a[rel='"+galleryID+"']").eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```